# EROR : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

why I get the error like this in my script

*Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

This is my script

```php
$result = $this->get_content($this->domain . 'mandiri-mutasi/get/' . $key . '/' . $username . '/' . $password . '/' . $nomor_rekening);
$trx = json_decode($result);
$transactions = array();
foreach ($trx as $row) {
    $transactions[] = array('tanggal' => $row->tanggal, 
                            'keterangan' => str_replace("'", '', $row->keterangan), 
                            'debet' => $row->debet, 
                            'kredit' => $row->kredit);
}
return $transactions;
```

Comment: Print out `$trx` and see what it is.

Comment: confirm that valid value in `$trx`, also check in `if` before pass it to `foreach`